# Software used to create this diagram from a patent

Tags: diagram

I know this question has been asked like a lot but I really need help on this. Attached below is an image of the diagram taken  from US 7535131 patent. [Here is the link](https://www.google.com/patents/US7535131) where you can find the similar images if you want to have a look.
[image: US 7535131 diagram image]

Can anyone please help me to find the software which was used to create diagrams like these? I doubt it could be AutoCAD but not really sure about that. I was working on a project and have got some diagrams to create, now there are tons of software available but I was really interested to find the software used here.

*Also if this was not the right place to ask the question kindly move this to appropriate place.*

Thank you for the support.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just mspaint?

Comment: Well it could be anything. I was trying to be sure if there's some program out there that can be used to create the diagrams effectively without much of a fuss!
Of course, this can be created using any software, but I was curious to know about the software, if any.

Comment: I'm sure someone more knowledgeable will be along soon, but to me the level of crappiness and general simplicity suggests mspaint, or some equally basic editor.

Comment: @BeB00 also its really hard for mspaint to be here. As there is a great level of symmetry here. There is some software that allows snapping as well as one click flipping, rotation and a layer based design layout for sure. 

AutoCAD seems a fair candidate, but I just want to know if there are some other options. Some parts of this diagrams feels more like hand-drawn!

Comment: It is possible that everything but the freehand callout lines is done in one of the many vector graphics programs and the result is imported into a pixel graphics program to add the callout lines. That is what I would do.

Comment: Looks like something that could be done in Visio.

Comment: Given the technology level of the patent office or typical lawyer's offices, it could be done by a draftsman in pen and ink. More likely it's done in a drawing program like Illustrator than in a tool designed for technical diagrams.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Yep, seems a fair answer. I have myself been doing like this except for the raster based callout part.

Comment: @ThePhoton seems fair!

Comment: @ThePhoton is probably right about most patents, but an individual inventor might not want to pay a patent lawyer to hire an artist.

Comment: Visio seems to be universal among the patent attorney's/agents I've dealt with.

Comment: The hand-drawn feeling might be due to the patent process: It was probably drawn on a computer, then submitted as printed paper, and finally scanned by the patent office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not sure what was actually used for the diagram above for your own use I would suggest taking a look at [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) which is:

- Inkscape is a professional vector graphics editor
- for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.
- It's free and open source.
- Outputs as .svg, Scaled Vector Graphics, files which can be resized without loss of resolution.

Comment: And, don't forget that it produces scalable vector graphics which will display the same at any resolution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics

Comment: @Mawg : Good point added!

Comment: @SteveBarnes and Mawg thanks for answering. 
So basically its the usual way of either using the domain specific software like AutoCAD and use its output, else draw the diagram all in 2D either directly using computer or hand drawn and trace it digitally using any vector based software.